# Rendering CALayer in context uses large amounts of memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, calayer, snapshot

I am taking a snapshot of a `UIWebView` layer, but when I render the webview's layer in the current context my app uses 10 MB more memory, and I don't think that should be right. Here is my current code:

```
CGSize imageSize = self.bounds.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.layer  renderInContext:context];
_snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: What exactly is `self` and how large is its bounds size?

Comment: self is the UIWebView, and the bounds in portrait mode would be (0,0,320,416)